# Linq to Entities - Speed question

Tags: performance, linq-to-entities, entity-relationship

I've got 3 tables, Person, Worker and Job.

Worker inherits from Person.
Each Worker can have 0..1 Job. But a Job can have multiple Workers.

Because Worker inherits from Person they are in the same table within the database (with a mapping on PersonType).

Now my database gave some trouble together with my model (about foreign keys), so I deleted my relations within the database.

So now I've only relations within the datamodel (in visual studio).

Is this a bad thing? **Is there a speedreduction when the relations aren't within my database but only in the datamodel?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A foreign key has nothing to do with a performance in general. It is only a constraint to keep your data consistent. So, you can expect only consistency problems with your data by removing your relation. If you need to troubleshoot performance problems - look at the indexes that your table has.

Comment: Thanks anthares, I only wanted to know if the relations within the database made my performance better. If not my question is answered. I'll accept your answer if nobody disagrees within a short time. Thanks!

Comment: You might also want to check the following link http://www.microsoft.com/technet/abouttn/flash/tips/tips_122104.mspx Depending on what database you are using it might affect performance (both in good and bad direction). But this is relies on internal implementation of your db and rarely can be predicted ... I personally disregard it.